# Cannot see added layer in Table of contents arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am using a Python script to add a layer to my mxd. Following is the script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Amruta\clustereddata.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
print arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0].name
lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Amruta\clusternewlayers.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyrFile)
```

I add this script in arches Python window itself. But I don't see any addition of layer in table of contents.

Then to test I just printed the name of file layer name which shows the new layer name

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
print lyr.name
```

output is `clusternewlayer`

Did I miss anything here? Why don't I see the layer in table of contents or over the map?
I refreshed the map but I still don't see my layer in table of contents.

Comment: Did you try running [`arcpy.RefreshTOC()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000001m000000)?

Comment: I did try this which was not helpful but "Current" worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Amruta\clustereddata.mxd")
```

won't alter the map document in the application, but the document of disk. Use

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
```

and then your script should work.